# Laravel - Add trailing slash with Redirect::route()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-3

I'm trying to add a slash to the end of the URL after I use `Redirect::route()` with Laravel.
I've tried numerous examples but couldnt find an answer.

This is what I have so far:

`routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return Redirect::route('login');
});


Route::get('/login/', array(
    'as'    => 'login',
    'uses'  => 'Controller@login'
));
```

`Controller.php`:

```
public function login()
{
    return 'Login page';
}
```

When I go to `htdocs/laravel_project/`, I get redirected to `htdocs/laravel_project/login` but I want it to be `htdocs/laravel_project/login/`. I want to add that slash to the end of the URL. If I do manually enter the slash at the URL it does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling [`Redirect::route`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ec1b1ae72c241c0d0fa576f18e2615b533379423/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L144-L158) which translates to:

> Redirect to the URL ([with trailing slash trimmed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ec1b1ae72c241c0d0fa576f18e2615b533379423/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L493-L504)) of a corresponding route.

Notice that Laravel will automatically remove the trailing slash of generated URL.

So, without further/deeper investigation, the fastest method would be:

```
return Redirect::to(URL::route('login') . '/');
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Redirect::to('example/page' . '\/', 301);
```

Use Redirect::to instead of Redirect::route and add `. '\/'` to the route

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit late but this trick helped me recently.

The `Redirect::to` method still removes "/" from the end of URL and I got nasty Internal redirect issue from SEO reports - non "/" was redirecting to the place I wanted, that was a chain of 2 redirects instead of direct redirect to the final place.

For Laravel 5.8 and above (I didn't test earlier version) I used `Redirect::away` method to save trailing slash in the end of URL.

So you can use this function to avoid internal redirect issue:

```
Redirect::away(URL::route('login') . '/',301);
```